# Three.js objloader + texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been using Three.js for a few weeks now, I managed to apply a texture to a cube created directly via the code, but once I tried to load an OBJ file with `OBJLoader`I noticed that I couldn't use the same method to load simple png or jpg textures with `TextureLoader`.

Now I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong, if either this is not the right way to do it, if I just can't load a simple image fine or if I'm not applying it right.

I've seen that applying a texture seems quite easy to do with an MTL file, but unfortunately I'm not sure how to make one.

My current code looks like something like this:

```
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
        loader.load( 'models/tshirt.obj', function ( object ) {

            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.y = -200;
            object.scale.x = 10;
            object.scale.y = 10;
            object.scale.z = 10;
            obj = object;
            texture = THREE.TextureLoader('img/crate.png'),
            material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture } );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( object, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

        } );
```

But it just doesn't seem to work. The model doesn't load and gives me random errors from Three.js. If instead of the code above I change `scene.add( obj);` the model actually loads.

What should I be doing here? Should I just go ahead and try to make an MTL file?

My full working code can bee seen at http://creativiii.com/3Dproject/old-index.html

EDIT: The error I get when adding mesh instead of obj is

```
three.min.js:436 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined
```

Comment: Chances are the errors aren't random. You should post them here as they are likely to be relevant.

Comment: Added, but I really doubt it'll help

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue in the meantime?

Comment: I did and I didn't. I kept having problems using jpgs and images, so I just found it easier to apply a canvas as a texture and change images on that.

Answer (score 9):

Try this code:

```
var OBJFile = 'my/mesh.obj';
var MTLFile = 'my/mesh.mtl';
var JPGFile = 'my/texture.jpg';

new THREE.MTLLoader()
.load(MTLFile, function (materials) {
    materials.preload();
    new THREE.OBJLoader()
        .setMaterials(materials)
        .load(OBJFile, function (object) {
            object.position.y = - 95;
            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(JPGFile);

            object.traverse(function (child) {   // aka setTexture
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    child.material.map = texture;
                }
            });
            scene.add(object);
        });
});
```

The texture loading changes was taken from: [How to apply texture on an object loaded by OBJLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809423/how-to-apply-texture-on-an-object-loaded-by-objloader) .

Comment: Thanks bro, You did me a big favor.